# The text didn't show on the textview in the ListView

Tags: android, listview

I try to use the ListView to show the data. It can show the text like the following picture.
I am sure it is working.

[image]

I add the the title in front of each text. I want it show like the following picture.

[image]

But it only show the title like the following

[image]

The code of `fitnessdata.xml` is like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Start_time_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/StartTime"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Start_time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Start_time_title"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/End_time_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Start_time_title"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/EndTime"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/End_time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/End_time_title"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/distance_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/End_time_title"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/distance"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/distance_title"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>      

</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I change from `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` , it can show the text like the following picture.

[image]

The code of define in JAVA file is like the following:

```
private static ListView fitness_data_list; 
private SimpleAdapter simpleadapter;
private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> fitnessdatalist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
```

The code of add data text is like the following:

```
HashMap<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
item.put("startTime", FitnessData[times][0]);
item.put("endTime", FitnessData[times][5]);
item.put("distance", FitnessData[times][6]);
item.put("stepcount", FitnessData[times][7]);
fitnessdatalist.add(item);
fitness_data_list.setAdapter(simpleadapter);
```

Why the text didn't show in the ListView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

For your `textview` in xml layout

i.e. simply use this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Start_time_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/StartTime"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Start_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Start_time_title"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/End_time_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Start_time_title"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/EndTime"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/End_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/End_time_title"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/distance_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/End_time_title"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/distance"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/distance_title"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>      

</RelativeLayout>
```